# Animations Lagging When Publishing from Flash CS6 To iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, flash, air, flash-cs6

I recently created an app in flash cs6 to be used on my iPhone 4.
The app doesnt need to work through the app store its just a tech demo but when i put the app on my device all the animations become really slow/choppy.
My iPhones up to date and im using air3.2 (i did try updating to air 3.7 but then my application just became a white screen)
I have also tried cacheing all the movie clips as bitmaps bit it doesnt seem to make a difference.

(the app works fine inside the flash simulator)

please help?!

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few reasons why this is happening,as I am taking a punt here as you havent gave much information on what your doing.
 but your frame rate may have effect.. how are you creating your tweens?timeline animation or tween scripts.I found tween scripting works better as its distance over time opposed to distance over frames.

Also depending on your animation, images sizes, event listeners etc..
You need to take inconsideration your device itself and the resources it has available, free memory or actual storage available.

The reason it will work freely on your PC would be due to the fact of less limitations, your pc has more to computes and resources to throw at your application .

Add this line to your code to check your memory:

```
    import flash.filesystem.File;

    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,performMemTest);

    function performMemTest(e:Event):void {
    trace(System.totalMemory);
    }
```

I have read anywhere around 14MB++you may experience problems.

Comment: Im using movieclips animated inside a timeline.

its set for 24FPS (iPhone default)
Im not sure its a memory issue, because everything else works fine its just the animations.

Comment: this could be your problem:movieclips animated inside a timeline